# TomEE Maven plugin Auto Reloading

Tags: java, maven, apache-tomee

I am unable to use the auto reload feature of maven plugin for TomEE documented [here](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-9.0/docs/maven/index.html). I am using the command **mvn clean install package tomee:run** to start and after some code change, using **mvn compile** in another terminal on the project folder to trigger the auto reload, with the exception "Can't lookup Deployer".
Follows to pom and stacktrace:

```
<groupId>codes.username</groupId>
<artifactId>algorithms</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>algorithms</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>algorithms</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <deployOpenEjbApplication>true</deployOpenEjbApplication>
                <tomeeVersion>9.0.0</tomeeVersion>
                <tomeeClassifier>plume</tomeeClassifier>
                <synchronization>
                    <extensions>
                        <extension>.class
                        </extension>
                    </extensions>
                </synchronization>
                <reloadOnUpdate>true</reloadOnUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
[INFO] Reloading F:\fontes\workspaces\Java\IdeaProjects\cm_algorithms\target\apache-tomee\webapps\cm_algorithms
fev. 07, 2023 6:50:02 AM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
INFORMAÃıES: RemoteInitialContextCreated{providerUri=http://localhost:8080/tomee/ejb}
07-Feb-2023 06:50:03.388 ADVERT├èNCIA [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service "null OEJP/4.6" FAIL "Security error - [Ljava.net.URI; is not whitelisted as deserialis
able, prevented before loading it, customize tomee.serialization.class.blacklist and tomee.serialization.class.whitelist to add it to not fail there. -Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=- -Dtomee
.serialization.class.whitelist=[Ljava.net.URI; for instance (or in conf/system.properties)." - Debug for StackTrace
fev. 07, 2023 6:50:03 AM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
ADVERT╩NCIA: RequestFailed{server=http://localhost:8080/tomee/ejb} JNDI_LOOKUP:/openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote {error=Prematurely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : Unable to read protocol 
version.  Reached the end of the stream.}
Exception in thread "tomee-maven-plugin-synchronizer" org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: Can't lookup Deployer
        at org.apache.openejb.maven.plugin.UpdatableTomEEMojo.deployer(UpdatableTomEEMojo.java:398)
        at org.apache.openejb.maven.plugin.UpdatableTomEEMojo.reload(UpdatableTomEEMojo.java:247)
        at org.apache.openejb.maven.plugin.UpdatableTomEEMojo$SynchronizerRedeployer.run(UpdatableTomEEMojo.java:279)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot lookup '/openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote'. [Root exception is java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot read the response from the server (OEJP/4.6) : Prematur
ely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end of the stream.; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Prematurely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end of the stream.]
        at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.lookup(JNDIContext.java:453)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at org.apache.openejb.maven.plugin.UpdatableTomEEMojo.deployer(UpdatableTomEEMojo.java:396)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot read the response from the server (OEJP/4.6) : Prematurely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end o
f the stream.; nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Prematurely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end of the stream.
        at org.apache.openejb.client.Client.processRequest(Client.java:395)
        at org.apache.openejb.client.Client.request(Client.java:140)
        at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.request(JNDIContext.java:236)
        at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.lookup(JNDIContext.java:443)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Prematurely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end of the stream.
        at org.apache.openejb.client.Exceptions.newIOException(Exceptions.java:44)
        at org.apache.openejb.client.Client.processRequest(Client.java:280)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end of the stream.
        at org.apache.openejb.client.ProtocolMetaData.readExternal(ProtocolMetaData.java:103)
        at org.apache.openejb.client.Client.processRequest(Client.java:276)
        ... 9 more
```

I tried to add the true line, use Java 11 instead of 17.
When I try the command "reload" on the active terminal of TomEE, I get a similar error:

```
Can't lookup Deployer: Cannot lookup '/openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote'. Cannot read the response from the server (OEJP/4.6) : Prematurely reached the end of the stream.  OEJP/4.6 : 
Unable to read protocol version.  Reached the end of the stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below, thanks.

https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/configuration/live-reload/cdi

```js
<systemVariables>
    <openejb.system.apps>true</openejb.system.apps>
    <tomee.serialization.class.blacklist>-</tomee.serialization.class.blacklist>
</systemVariables>
```

Comment: It would be great to pinpoint what exactly has changed from OP's code and why, without needing to visit the link (links might be dead in the future).